# Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I send a post request to the ip address but I get an error. The error is this;
message:'Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: 100.64.xx.xxx is not in the cert's list: '

P.s.: I get error 500 error when I add rejectUnauthorized false.
[image]

Comment: TLS/SSL does not work with IP Addresses. They validate the Hostname. Not the IP Address

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Marc. IP Address comes to me from somewhere so I have no chance to change it. Is there anything you can suggest?

Comment: Set a valid tld (example.com) to the ip. (A Record) The IP looks suspicious... Is this one from the "Carrier Grade NAT" (100.64.0.0/10) subnet? As sayed, set a valid A record to the ip with a top level doamin, and issue a cert for the domain name.